# How do I associate an ssh key pair with the instance created by a stack in Amazon CloudFormation?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudformation

Previously I have created an EC2 instance based on an image. During the creation process the Amazon wizard created a key pair and then provided it to me so I could connect.

Now I am trying to use CloudFormation instead, so that my new server has some basic software installed (LAMP stack). But the EC2 instance I end up with has no ssh key pair that I can find.

Is there a way to associate a key pair while creating a stack on CloudFormation?

I've read that there are ways to add the key to the instance's volume by stopping the instance, creating a clone, plus some other steps. But my admin skills in this area are not that strong so I am hoping for something that is (for me) more straightforward.

Hope this makes sense - any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there a way to associate a key pair while creating a stack on
>   CloudFormation?

Sure, it indeed works by associating an existing key pair of yours during the process; the [AWS CloudFormation Sample Templates](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-templates/) feature respective fragments, e.g. the [Simple EC2 instance example](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/EC2InstanceSample.template) contains the fragment you are looking for:

```
  "Parameters" : {
    "KeyName" : {
      "Description" : "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instance",
      "Type" : "String"
    }
  },

  [...]

  "Resources" : {
    "Ec2Instance" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties" : {
        "KeyName" : { "Ref" : "KeyName" },
        "ImageId" : { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "RegionMap", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "AMI" ]},
        "UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" : "80" }
      }
    }
  },
```

This fragment enables passing the desired key pair name as a parameter, alternatively you could embed the name directly or simply provide a default one.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks much... I was choosing from the dropdown list of sample templates, and I think the template I got that way did not have the parameter for the key. Having the template URL that you linked to was a big help. That template had the key parameter I needed.

Answer (score 6):

AWS CloudFormation parameters can also give you a list of all key's that are available in your account & region. Just change the "Type" of the parameter to the desired AWS type. That will be "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName" in this case.

With "CloudFormation Parameter Types", the above example will be:

```
"Parameters" : {
  "KeyName" : {
    "Description" : "EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instance",
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName"
  },
},
[...]

"Resources" : {
  "Ec2Instance" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
    "Properties" : {
      "KeyName" : { "Ref" : "KeyName" },
      "ImageId" : { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "RegionMap", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "AMI" ]},
      "UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" : "80" }
    }
  }
},
```

I hope this helps.

See also: https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx3DV2UYG9SC38G/Using-the-New-CloudFormation-Parameter-Types